# Integrating a function with sympy - sympy.polys.polyerrors.PolynomialDivisionFailed error

Tags: sympy

I'm new to using Sympy, and wish to use it to integrate the following function. Although, I get this error which I'm not sure how to resolve.

```
import sympy as sy

A = sy.Symbol('A')
B = sy.Symbol('B')
C = sy.Symbol('C')
D = sy.Symbol('D')
x = sy.Symbol('x', positive=True)
y = sy.Symbol('y', positive=True)

def func(x,y):
  return (1.0/(4.0*x*y))*(A*sy.log( ((y+x)**2 + C**2)/((y-x)**2 + C**2) ) - B*sy.log( ((y+x)**2 + D**2)/((y-x)**2 + D**2) ))

sy.integrate(func(x,y), (x,0,10))
```

Although, when I run this I get the following error and I'm not sure how to resolve this.

```
sympy.polys.polyerrors.PolynomialDivisionFailed: couldn't reduce degree in a polynomial division
 algorithm when dividing [(-1.13305359211433e+221*y**2 + 5.66526796057163e+220*D**2 + 
5.66526796057163e+220*C**2)/1.57368554460323e+219, 0.0, (3.39916077634298e+221*y**4 - 
1.13305359211433e+221*y**2*D**2 - 1.13305359211433e+221*y**2*C**2 + 5.66526796057163e+220*D**4 + 
2.26610718422865e+221*D**2*C**2 + 5.66526796057163e+220*C**4)/1.57368554460323e+219, 0.0, 
(-3.39916077634298e+221*y**6 - 1.69958038817149e+221*y**4*D**2 - 1.69958038817149e+221*y**4*C**2
 - 1.69958038817149e+221*y**2*D**4 + 6.79832155268595e+221*y**2*D**2*C**2 - 
1.69958038817149e+221*y**2*C**4 + 1.69958038817149e+221*D**4*C**2 + 
1.69958038817149e+221*D**2*C**4)/1.57368554460323e+219, 0.0, (1.13305359211433e+221*y**8 + 
2.26610718422865e+221*y**6*D**2 + 2.26610718422865e+221*y**6*C**2 + 
1.13305359211433e+221*y**4*D**4 + 4.5322143684573e+221*y**4*D**2*C**2 + 
1.13305359211433e+221*y**4*C**4 + 2.26610718422865e+221*y**2*D**4*C**2 + 
2.26610718422865e+221*y**2*D**2*C**4 + 1.13305359211433e+221*D**4*C**4)/1.57368554460323e+219, 
0.0] by [(-2.0203139355353e+661*y**6 + 3.93961217429382e+662*y**4*D**2 + 
3.93961217429382e+662*y**4*C**2 - 2.42437672264235e+662*y**2*D**4 - 
3.03047090330294e+662*y**2*D**2*C**2 - 2.42437672264235e+662*y**2*C**4 + 
2.52539241941912e+661*D**6 - 1.51523545165146e+661*D**4*C**2 - 1.51523545165146e+661*D**2*C**4 + 
2.52539241941912e+661*C**6)/3.15674052427389e+659, 0.0, (6.06094180660588e+661*y**8 - 
8.08125574214117e+662*y**6*D**2 - 8.08125574214117e+662*y**6*C**2 + 
3.18199444846809e+662*y**4*D**4 + 2.47488457103073e+663*y**4*D**2*C**2 + 
3.18199444846809e+662*y**4*C**4 - 1.51523545165147e+661*y**2*D**6 - 
7.92973219697602e+662*y**2*D**4*C**2 - 7.92973219697602e+662*y**2*D**2*C**4 - 
1.51523545165147e+661*y**2*C**6 + 2.52539241941911e+661*D**8 + 1.51523545165147e+661*D**6*C**2 - 
2.02031393553529e+661*D**4*C**4 + 1.51523545165147e+661*D**2*C**6 + 
2.52539241941911e+661*C**8)/3.15674052427389e+659, 0.0, (-6.06094180660588e+661*y**10 + 
3.93961217429382e+662*y**8*D**2 + 3.93961217429382e+662*y**8*C**2 - 
6.06094180660588e+661*y**6*D**4 + 9.6975068905694e+662*y**6*D**2*C**2 - 
6.06094180660588e+661*y**6*C**4 + 1.38707976084194e+646*y**4*D**6 - 
4.24265926462411e+662*y**4*D**4*C**2 - 4.24265926462411e+662*y**4*D**2*C**4 + 
1.38707976084194e+646*y**4*C**6 - 3.03047090330294e+661*y**2*D**8 - 
2.42437672264235e+662*y**2*D**6*C**2 - 2.42437672264235e+662*y**2*D**4*C**4 - 
2.42437672264235e+662*y**2*D**2*C**6 - 3.03047090330294e+661*y**2*C**8 + 
3.03047090330294e+661*D**8*C**2 + 1.73384970105243e+646*D**6*C**4 + 
1.73384970105243e+646*D**4*C**6 + 3.03047090330294e+661*D**2*C**8)/3.15674052427389e+659, 0.0, 
(2.02031393553529e+661*y**12 + 2.02031393553529e+661*y**10*D**2 + 
2.02031393553529e+661*y**10*C**2 - 1.51523545165147e+661*y**8*D**4 + 
1.01015696776765e+661*y**8*D**2*C**2 - 1.51523545165147e+661*y**8*C**4 - 
1.01015696776765e+661*y**6*D**6 - 3.03047090330294e+661*y**6*D**4*C**2 - 
3.03047090330294e+661*y**6*D**2*C**4 - 1.01015696776765e+661*y**6*C**6 + 
5.05078483883823e+660*y**4*D**8 - 1.01015696776765e+661*y**4*D**6*C**2 - 
1.01015696776765e+661*y**4*D**4*C**4 - 1.01015696776765e+661*y**4*D**2*C**6 + 
5.05078483883823e+660*y**4*C**8 + 1.01015696776765e+661*y**2*D**8*C**2 + 
1.01015696776765e+661*y**2*D**6*C**4 + 1.01015696776765e+661*y**2*D**4*C**6 + 
1.01015696776765e+661*y**2*D**2*C**8 + 5.05078483883823e+660*D**8*C**4 + 
1.01015696776765e+661*D**6*C**6 + 5.05078483883823e+660*D**4*C**8)/3.15674052427389e+659].
 This can happen when it's not possible to detect zero in the coefficient domain. The domain of 
computation is RR(B,y,D,C). Zero detection is guaranteed in this coefficient domain. This may 
indicate a bug in SymPy or the domain is user defined and doesn't implement zero detection 
properly.
```

Has anyone had this issue before and if so, how exactly can this be solved? I have varied the limits of $x$ but I get the same error!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Seems to be a known issue with floats, which is fair enough if you know how these sort of algorithms go. The solution is to use sympy rationals https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/12879

Comment: Ah, ok. So, I just need to wrap the function in a simplify method? So, along the lines of sy.simplify(sy.integrate(sy.simplify(func(x,y)), (x,1e-4,10))) ? I've just tried this and I get the same error. I did notice that some of the constants where extremely high, like the original post above, at 1e600! Could that be a potential issue?

Comment: Hmm, no I don't think so, it's more like you need to wrap this 1.0 and 4.0 you have in that 'S' thing that is mentioned, and linked to https://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html#python-numbers-vs-sympy-numbers. The issue is basically that the the numbers get extremely large and extremely small yeah. If you use floats then sympy will run into precision problems and probably end up doing things like trying to divide by zero. Wrapping the func in simpifys is no good because at that point the func already has floats in it, and there's no way to retroactively turn them into rationals.

Comment: Ah right! I see what you mean now! So, the issue is because I'm using python floats which causes precision issues! I've just changed the expression to have python integers, i.e 1/(4*x*y). And, the calculation is now running and hasn't crashed *yet*. Hopefully, it'll work now! Thank you for the help!

Comment: In this case you can avoid floats just by replacing `1.0` and `4.0` with `1` and `4`.  But your functions seems to be much too heavy to be integrated with sympy, especially as there can happen divisions by zero and logarithms of negative numbers.

Comment: I did specify x and y to be positive only. So, that would remove the issue of negative values within the log, and the value of C and D are the minimum value for the logarithms. Although, I should possible label them as constants rather than symbols?